# UIDocumentInteractionController and lazy loading

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, lazy-loading

**EDIT :** Is it possible to open remote file ? Or I must download it before ?

How can I show an empty `UIDocumentInteractionController`, while the file to show is downloading, and once downloaded, refresh the `UIDocumentInteractionController` to show the file ? Thanks.